# Multiple query on PHP dows not work

Tags: php, mysqli

Consider this simple PHP page:

```
<?php

  $db = new mysqli("localhost", "myuser", "mypwd", "mydb");
    if ($db->connect_error)
      // Dying sequence;

    // Executing query
    $qres = $db->multi_query("SET @rank = -1; SELECT * FROM (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 as rank, field1, field2 FROM mytable WHERE field1 = 'value') AS T1 WHERE rank = 2;");
    $db->commit();
    if (!qres) {
      // Problems in query
      // Dying
      $db->close();
      return;
    }
    if (!($qres->num_rows == 1)) {
      // Error fetched
      $numrows = $qres->num_rows;
      $db->close();
      // Dying
      return;
    }

    // Returning
    echo "ALLOK";

    $db->close();

  ?>
```

Well, this does not work.
either if I use `query` or `multi_query`

Can you help me?

Comment: "if (!qres)" may be the fatal typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to select the 3rd row from some table. Though the rank will be nondeterministic since you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause for that inner query.

You don't need this variable and multiple queries to do that.

Use an offset in the `LIMIT` clause, along with an `ORDER BY` clause, instead.

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM mytable WHERE field1 = 'value' ORDER BY something LIMIT 2,1
```